# Apply css for radcalendar dynamically

Tags: asp.net, css, telerik

Currently I am working on RadCalendar. My requirement is Calendar has to be started from current month and we should have only NEXT navigation button. When user navigates to next month, then the PREV navigation icon had to be displayed along with NEXT navigation icon.

How can I achieve this????

For test purpose I created a TelerikStyle.css and placed the below code:

```
BODY
{
margin: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
font-size: 32px;
font-family: Arial;
}


.MyRadCalendar .rcTitlebar a.rcPrev 
.MyRadCalendar .rcTitlebar a.rcFastPrev, 
.MyRadCalendar .rcTitlebar a.rcNext, 
.MyRadCalendar .rcTitlebar a.rcFastNext 
{ 
  visibility: hidden; 

}
```

And I am creating this Radcalendar dynamically. So I tried to attach to apply this CSS Styles to Radcalender through below way.

```
_myCalendar.CssFile = "~/stylesheets/TelerikStyle.css";
_myCalendar.TitleStyle.CssClass = "rcTitlebar";
```

But my navigation buttons are not hiding. So please tell me how to apply CSS Styles for Radcalender dynamically. And How to achieve my above requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Each of the Telerik Skins actually have a minimum height and width setting for the RadCalendar in order to ensure that the visual styles of the control are not broken.

As you can imagine modifying the width and height to arbitrary settings could skew the look and feel of the control quite a bit. 
What you can do, however, is either modify one of the existing skins or create your own.

This section http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/calendar-custom-skin.html in their online documentation covers how to change the appearance, and the specific article covers how to create a custom skin.

Thanks
AB

Comment: Hi AB, Thanks for you suggestion. I will go with custom skin design. But can you help me in linking this CSS file to Radcalendar. I am not using any aspx or ascx pages. I am dynamically creating the RadCalendar through .cs page. So, can you tell me wat line of code will help me in getting this CSS properties applied to my radcalender.

Comment: Also can you help me in acheving my requirement like  Calendar has to be started from current month and we should have only NEXT navigation button. When user navigates to next month, then the PREV navigation icon had to be displayed along with NEXT navigation icon.